# Odata filter on cached data

Tags: caching, filter, odata

Say for instance we want to pull back a list of 50 individuals. When using odata with this filter, $top=2&$skip=4, it is returning those 2 records, but what we are wanting to do is possibly sending back 50 individuals, and be able to run the filter against those.

When I debug my program, I run it to get the 50, and every subsequent call brings me the 50 back from cache. When I run the same thing, but add the following $top=2&$skip=4, it runs through my code and gets all the records and returns the two objects from the code, not the cache.

```
GetIndividuals(ODataQueryOptions<Individuals> opts)
    {
       .....
        var results = opts.ApplyTo(objAll.AsQueryable(), settings);

        return new PageResult<Individual>(
            results as IEnumerable<Individual>,
            Request.ODataProperties().NextLink,
            objAll.AsQueryable().Count());
    }
```

I hope this is clear.....any ideas on how to return a larger group of data and then run odata on it after the fact?

Comment: I am not sure that i understand your requirement clearly. Basically, OData Query options, such as $top, $skip, etc are conditions applied to your data source. And It's up to you to control the conditions are running before or after.
So, would you show us some sample codes?

Comment: Basically this will pull back 10,000 rows, and applyes the filter to grab the top 2...or however many we request..and pass that back, and to get the next set of data, we have to query it again and again, getting all 10,000 records before we apply the filter. Basically, wanting to store the results off somewhere and then query against that...I tried caching, but it caches each search option as a different cache.